# How to fetch data from database into textbox on the basis of ComboBox Selected Change Event

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to load data from database on the basis of `selectedIndexChanged Event` of `ComboBox`. I have 2 `controls`, `cbDocName`and `tbDocFee`Meaning when i select Doc from `cbDocName`, that Doc fee should be loaded into tbDocFee. Following is the code and a picture attached

[image]

```
private void cbDocsName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetDocFees();
    }
    public void GetDocFees()
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DocFees FROM AddDoctor WHERE ID=@ID", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cbDocsName.Text);
            con.Open();
            tbDocFees.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        }
    }
```

The above code works perfectly but instead of showing docName in cbDocName, it shows DocID as `DisplayMember`. Here is the code on `form load event`

```
private void frmDocAppoinment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbDocsName.DataSource = DocAppoinmentSystem.Utillities.clsNewApp.LoadDocNameComboBox();
        cbDocsName.DisplayMember = "DocName";
        cbDocsName.ValueMember = "ID";
    }
```

UPDATED: LoadDocNameComboBox() Code is below

```
public static DataTable LoadDocNameComboBox()
    {
        DataTable dtCampus = new DataTable();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,DocName FROM AddDoctor WHERE DocStatus='PRESENT'", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dtCampus.Load(r);
            }
        }
        return dtCampus;
    }
```

NOTE: `cbDocName.SelectedIndex, cbDocName.SelectedText, cbDocName.SelectedItem` upon all of these, i get an error

> Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object

Comment: Might help to know what `LoadDocNameComboBox` returns, exactly.

Comment: Show what `LoadDocNameComboBox` does.

Comment: {LoadDocNameComboBox} returns DocName and DocID From Database and fill ComboBox

Comment: {LoadDocNameComboBox} returns DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cbDocsName.SelectedValue);
```

When loading your ComboBox you have set DocName as DisplayMember and ID as ValueMember.  On Selection therefore, the SelectedText becomes the name and the SelectedValue becomes the ID.  So in retrieving fee data from the database, you need to refer to the value, or in this case SelectedValue.

EDIT

Also please note that you have to set ValueMember and DisplayMember before DataSource.  So you need:

```
cbDocsName.DisplayMember = "DocName"; 
cbDocsName.ValueMember = "ID"; 
cbDocsName.DataSource = LoadDocNameComboBox();
```

Comment: By using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cbDocsName.SelectedValue);` I got an error 

An Exception of type System.ArgumentException occured in system.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No mapping Exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to unknown managed provider native type.

Comment: ` tbDocFees.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` on this line, I change {Scalar} to {Reader} but no help

Comment: What type is DocFees

Comment: DockFees DataType is nVarchar

Comment: Try tbDocFees.Text = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Still Got the Same Error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152911/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-affaq).

Comment: GOD BLESSED YOU MAN

Answer (score 0):

Please check the object list that your DocAppoinmentSystem.Utillities.clsNewApp.LoadDocNameComboBox()
is returning. I am sure the property you are using for DisplayMember has a different name. Please check "DocName" property. May be a simple spelling mistake.

Comment: There is not any spelling mistake